# UICollectionView set 3 cells per row to fit the width of the screen

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, autolayout

The iPhone screen width is 320 pt as we know. I need to add 3 cells per row and my UICollections width also 320.

But the problem here:

if use for example 106pt for the cell width then we have 2 pt space, between cells. And this is correct because the collection view automatically place cells. If I use 107 pt for the cell width then collection view displays only 2 cells per row, and this is also correct, but not for my purposes.

Of coerces I can check for example each 2 cell in the code and set for this cell 108 pt instead of 106 pt, but maybe there is another good solution with constraint for example?